# Change a list view through it's onItemListener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I made an onTouchListener to a list view that checks which item (string in my case) in that list was clicked and it's position. I want to take out that string of the list, so I made a method that gets the array adpter's string array and the poistion the list was touched and returns a new array that is the same but without the string that was touched. now I want to update the list view adapter to the new array, how do I do that?
thanks

Comment: I don't see a question mark. Are you asking a question?

Comment: lol, I changed it to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is set a change notification to the array adapter via the [BaseAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).
This will refresh the entire list view. Note: this must be called in the main thread.

EDIT:

To clear some confusion you have to first fetch the Adapter from your list view. This is done by [calling myListView.getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getAdapter%28%29). So you could do

```
myListView.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Comment: You write ???.notifyDatasetChanged where ??? is the adapter object you gave the ListView.

Comment: ok thank you, and I can't do it from the listener? then is there a simpler then "notify" the outside of the lisetener through a variable or something that it needs to call this method?

Comment: You can do it from the listener. You just need to have scope access to your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

just call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter to reload it

Comment: if you mean to just write it in the adapter like you said before, then it gives me that problem: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}

Comment: No no, you have to fetch your ListView's adapter and call notifyDatasetChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the array in your adapter again.

```
listView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this, yourArray));
```

Comment: but that and BaseAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged are needed to be called outside of the listener, so the  convenience is the same, but you suggestion can be laggi if my array is very big

Comment: Each adapter view can only have one adapter. You would have to remove the old adapter from the list view and assign it a new one. This overall is much less effective (and much more time consuming) than just calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.